# Accessing PHP 7 Object Properties

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following array

```
$arrdata = array("CTypeID","TypeName","CTYPES","CID","COURSES","CTypeID");
```

this array is subjected to a function: `Generic2DataSideBar($arrdata);`
The definition of the called function is as follows:

```
function Generic2DataSideBar($data)
{
    //a generic array for data..
    //var_dump($data);
    $sdata= array();
    //this is the function for generating depended data...
    $this->load->model("Commons");
    $dat="SELECT ".$data[0].",".$data[1]." FROM ".$data[2];
    $result=$this->Commons->LoadResultSet($dat);
    //Looping through the resultset
    foreach ($result as $key) {
        //get the number of departments

        $da="SELECT ".$data[3]." FROM ".$data[4]." WHERE ".$data[5]."='".$key->$data[0]."'";
        $dat=count($this->Commons->LoadResultSet($da));

        $r=array($key->$data[1], $dat);
        array_push($sdata, $r);
    }
    header("content-type: application/json");
    $sdata=json_encode($sdata);
    return $sdata;
}
```

This function is working well in PHP 5.6.3 but when i upgraded to PHP 7, the line `$da="SELECT ".$data[3]." FROM ".$data[4]." WHERE ".$data[5]."='".$key->$data[0]."'";` brings a problem in that `$key->$data[0]` returns `''` All values are OK except that part. In PHP 7 can't one have something like `$key->"Data"` so long "Data" is a valid property name? Thanks

Comment: Try using `($key->$data)[0]` and Check backward incompatibility in variable handling with http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling

Comment: Thanks, but that is not working. Produces the same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect), the interpretation of `$key->$data[0]` changed from PHP 5 to PHP 7 (the second row of the table).

In order to get the same results as on PHP 5 you can do one of these:

1. extract `$data[0]` in a variable  and use that variable instead:

   ```
    $field = $data[0];
    "... WHERE ".$data[5]."='".$key->$field."'";
   ```
2. use curly braces to group the sub-expressions that need to be evaluated first:

   ```
    "... WHERE ".$data[5]."='".$key->{$data[0]}."'";
   ```

Both ways are compatible with PHP 5 and they do not change the behaviour of the code on PHP 5.

Comment: Opted to use option 2. Very clean and no more memory allocations. It worked like a charm! Thank you.